# Flutter Radio button not highlighting

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I built an app that has a list of users and a user can invite another user so I wanted the user to select multiple users at once and call the invite function I'm trying to accomplish this using a radio list tile button and when the user tap, it adds the user id to a list then when the user submits, the list is sent everything works fine but the problem is the radio list tile button group value does not get updated so the radio does not highlight so, the user does not know it's selected or not I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work so if anybody has an idea please help

```html
       List<String> users = [];
  List<String> userName = ['A', 'N', 'A', 'W', 'J', 'Jo'];
 
      void addRemoveFun(
    String selectedVal,
  ) {
    bool selected = users.contains(selectedVal);
    if (selected) {
      users.remove(selectedVal);
    } else {
      users.add(selectedVal);
    }
  }
```

```
  Widget buildRadio(int index) {
    return RadioListTile<List<String>>(
      activeColor: ContentTheme.userPreffered(context).greenHighlightColor,
      value: userName,
      groupValue: selectedNames,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          value = userName;
          addRemoveFun(userName[index]);
        });
      
        print('$selectedNames');
      },
      title: Text(
        "${userName[index]}",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: ContentTheme.userPreffered(context).bodyTextColor,
          fontSize: ContentSize.fromMediaSize(widget.mediaSize).tileTitleSize,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```dart
Widget buildRadio(int index) {
    return RadioListTile<List<String>>(
      activeColor: ContentTheme.userPreffered(context).greenHighlightColor,
      // Change userName to index
      value: index,
      // Change selectedNames to userName
      groupValue: userName[index],
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          // Change here
          userName = value;
          addRemoveFun(userName[index]);
        });
      
        print('$selectedNames');
      },
      title: Text(
        "${userName[index]}",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: ContentTheme.userPreffered(context).bodyTextColor,
          fontSize: ContentSize.fromMediaSize(widget.mediaSize).tileTitleSize,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much to begin with but your code have a lot of error, value can't be index cause of List<String> and even after i tried changing it to String and casting the index to string it kinda works but on tap it change the value of the userName with index